# How to fix MongoException_Network with Java (Morphia)

Tags: mongodb, networking, morphia

I'm using Morphia framework to connect to db mongoDB at ip internet.
Everything is good but sometime i have this error :(
I don't understand, please give me some suggest. Thanks

```
com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Read operation to server "ip:port" failed on database cloud_1
 at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:302)
 at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:273)
 at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:84)
 at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:66)
 at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:498)
 at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:621)
 at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:657)
 at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.hasNext(MorphiaIterator.java:57)
 at org.mongodb.morphia.query.QueryImpl.asList(QueryImpl.java:323)
 at oa.repository.SaleTransactionRepository.getListSaleTransactionByIdsAndEntityIds(SaleTransactionRepository.java:76)
 at oa.service.impl.LiveCampaignServiceImpl.detailChartPromoteYourProduct(LiveCampaignServiceImpl.java:161)
 at oa.service.impl.LiveCampaignServiceImpl.getCampaignDetailChart(LiveCampaignServiceImpl.java:124)
 at oa.controller.campaign.LiveCampaignController.getCampaignDetailChart(LiveCampaignController.java:124)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.inter..
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:73)
 at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:50)
 at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:37)
 at com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:42)
 at com.mongodb.DBPort$1.execute(DBPort.java:164)
 at com.mongodb.DBPort$1.execute(DBPort.java:158)
 at com.mongodb.DBPort.doOperation(DBPort.java:187)
 at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:158)
 at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:294)
 ... 103 more
```

Comment: I configured the morphia connection: 

Builder builder = MongoClientOptions.builder().autoConnectRetry(true).connectTimeout(150000)
     .socketKeepAlive(true).socketTimeout(600000);

   MongoClientOptions mco = builder.build();
   mongo = new MongoClient(addr, credentailList, mco);
but it's not working fine

Comment: Is this a remote MongoDB node? It really just looks you have some network problems.

Comment: @NicCottrell: yes. I'm newbie Mongodb, so i'm confused about this error.
I tried to reasearch and saw same error: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325884/com-mongodb-mongoexceptionnetwork-caused-by-java-net-sockettimeoutexception-r
but i understand "two datanode" ?

Comment: Does your error actually say "ip:port"? It looks like you need to update your code with "127.0.0.1:27017" to make your app connect to a MongoDB on localhost

Comment: "ip:port": i mean it's a ip internet, it's working. But sometime having that error

Comment: Did you try going back to default settings on the client? i.e. just `MongoClientOptions.builder().build()` ?

Comment: Yep, but it's same :(